# Breakpoint in ByteBuddy advice class with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I am looking for a way to debug an advice class within IntelliJ.

In the following code sample, ByteBuddy is replacing the constructor of `FileInputStream`.
The method `FileInputStreamCtorString.onEnter` is being called as expected, right before the call to the constructor.
However, there is a problem during the execution of the `onEnter` method, apparently related to calling some static method and setting static field.

I would like to put a breakpoint inside the `onEnter` method for further investigation.
How should I configure IntelliJ to make the breakpoint stop as expected?

```
package com.example.javaagent.instrumentation;

import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static java.util.logging.Level.FINE;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.*;



public class FileInputStreamConstructorInstrumentationTests2 {

    @Test
    public void testByteBuddyfileInputStreamConstructor() {
        ByteBuddyAgent.install();

        AgentBuilder.Identified.Extendable extendableAgentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
                .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError().withTransformationsOnly())
                .with(AgentBuilder.InstallationListener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
                .ignore(none())
                .type(named("java.io.FileInputStream"))
                .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice());

        extendableAgentBuilder = extendableAgentBuilder.transform(
                new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                        .include(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
                        .advice(
                                isConstructor().and(takesArguments(1)).and(takesArgument(0, String.class)),
                                this.getClass().getName() + "$FileInputStreamCtorString"));

        extendableAgentBuilder.installOnByteBuddyAgent();

        String filename = "example.txt";
        createFile(filename);
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            int data = inputStream.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) data);
                data = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        deleteFile(filename);
    }

    public static class FileInputStreamCtorString {
        public static boolean iveBeenHere = false;

        @Advice.OnMethodEnter(suppress = Throwable.class)
        public static void onEnter(@Advice.Argument(0) String name) {
            System.out.println("FileInputStreamCtorString: entered with param "+ name);
            System.out.println("FileInputStreamCtorString: second log line");
            JustPrint.sayHello();
            System.out.println("FileInputStreamCtorString: after calling static method");
            iveBeenHere = true;
            System.out.println("FileInputStreamCtorString: after setting static field");
        }
    }

    public static class JustPrint{
        public static void sayHello(){
            System.out.println("Did I say 'hello'?");
        }
    }

    private static void deleteFile(String filename) {
        File file = new File(filename);
        // Check if the file exists
        if (file.exists()) {
            // If the file exists, delete it
            if (file.delete()) {
                System.out.println("File deleted successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to delete file");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
        }
    }

    private static void createFile(String filename) {
        File file = new File(filename);
        // Check if the file already exists
        if (!file.exists()) {
            // If the file does not exist, create a new file
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("File created successfully");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File already exists");
        }
    }
}
```

When running the test `testByteBuddyfileInputStreamConstructor`, I get the following output:

```
[Byte Buddy] BEFORE_INSTALL net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$ByteBuddy$ModuleSupport@f9879ac on sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@37f21974
[Byte Buddy] REDEFINE BATCH #0 [1 of 1 type(s)]
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM java.io.FileInputStream [null, module java.base, Thread[Test worker,5,main], loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] REDEFINE COMPLETE 1 batch(es) containing 1 types [0 failed batch(es)]
[Byte Buddy] INSTALL net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$ByteBuddy$ModuleSupport@f9879ac on sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@37f21974
File created successfully
FileInputStreamCtorString: entered with param example.txt
FileInputStreamCtorString: second log line
File deleted successfully
```

So, I'm sure that the following source line is reached and I would like the debugger to stop there:

```
System.out.println("FileInputStreamCtorString: entered with param "+ name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte Buddy inlines advice code, meaning that your code is never executed, it only serves as a copy-paste template. You can set the `delegate` property in the enter and exit annotations to true if you wanted to invoke the advice methods instead.